# How to replace variables with values?

Tags: php, concatenation

```
$ext   = 'jpg';
$path  = './img/';

$capcha .=
'<div><span>'.$values[$i].' <input type="radio" name="capcha" value="'.$value2[$i].'"></span>
 <div style="background: url('.$path.$values[$i].'.'.$ext.');
 width:33px;
 ...
```

This works, but I want to replace `$ext` and `$path` variables with theirs values.

```
<div style="background: url('./img/'.$values[$i].'.jpg'.);
```

Errors: something is always unexpected.

Comment: This should alrady work, except the period at the end after extension

Comment: What do you mean by "replace ... with values"? What do `$values`, `$value2`, `$path` and `$i` contain? Is the piece of code in your example inside a loop?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, replace the two variables with `theirs` values. This is part of code to write a html content and css style using php. Everything works if I keep variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo i guess...

```
$capcha .=
'<div><span>'.$values[$i].' <input type="radio" name="capcha" value="'.$value2[$i].'"></span>
 <div style="background: url(./img/'.$values[$i].'.jpg);
 width:33px;
 ...
```

I guess this would work.

Or:

with escaping the single quotes:

```
$capcha .=
'<div><span>'.$values[$i].' <input type="radio" name="capcha" value="'.$value2[$i].'"></span>
 <div style="background: url(\'./img/'.$values[$i].'.jpg\');
 width:33px;
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
<div style="background: url(\''.$path.$values[$i].'.'.$ext.'\');
```

to have a result such as :

instead of

```
<div style="background: url(path);
```